# Edittext not display for emoji keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, emoji

EditText not seen when a keyboard is open. I have changed in 
 `android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustPan` manifest file and remove static keyboard height.
The keyboard does not update height as per the different size of devices (especially Samsung device)
I have also tried to get keyboard height and set emoji_keyboard layout and I followed this demo https://github.com/edsilfer/emoji-keyboard

**Assing emoji-keyboard layout height dynamically**

```
mRootWindow = getWindow();
mRootView = mRootWindow.getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
mRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout(){
        Rect r = new Rect();
        View view = mRootWindow.getDecorView();
        view.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        // r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom
    }
    });
```

Comment: DO you define onComputeInsets?  If so, post your code for it.  You can break the normal pan functionality by playing with this functions.

Comment: I changed keyboard height dynamically when keyboard open or close using above code but I don't get a specific event or keyboard height from onGlobalLayout listener

Comment: You can't change the keyboard height.  THe keyboard chooses its own height.  It's not possible to change it.  If you somehow manage to find a way to make the OS restrict it, you WILL break the keyboard.

Comment: I want to toggle between default keyboard and custom view like Whatsapp when you tap on emoji icon then appear custom emoji view same as Telegram.